# Non-destructive design around a circle/cylinder

Tags: procedural

I want to create a ring with smooth custom details around its rim. Basically a Blender alternative to SolidWorks wrap function.

Does anyone know how to create a ring like the one in the picture?

Ideally I want to make it non-destructively using curves.

Thanks in advanced

[image: a complex ring]

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you can do it with curves and full non-destructive, but here is a way to do it with mesh and destructive...  ;)

- Create your wave profile.
- Bend it 360° with the *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode.
- Give your object a *Solidify* modifier.
- Give it a *Bevel* modifier / *Angle* mode so that the angles will be sharp when you'll add the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. You might prefer a *Bevel* / *Weight* mode if you want to have a different bevel on top and bottom. Or add some edge loops instead of *Bevel* modifier.
- Add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to smooth your object, also, smooth it with *Smooth* shading option.
- It looks like you can't avoid the seam where the 360° shape joins, so I guess you need to apply the *Simple Deform* modifier.
- Once you've done it, remove the doubles so that it joins properly.
- Link-duplicate the ring with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.
- Rotate this copy 180° on the Y axis.
- Create the inner ring.

[image]

Comment: Not op, but this was actually really insightful, thanks

Comment: Thanks! Shame it cant be done with curves - would be a lot quicker and smoother. What you've done looks really good tho.I'll give it a try and post the result soon. If it looks right, it is right!! Cheers.

Comment: I've tried with curves but could not figure out how to do it, but maybe someone will propose a solution   ;)

Comment: Its actually quite easy to make the ring by using a circle curve instead of the simple deform modifier, but I guess you want the shape itself be made using curves

Comment: Hello HenrikD, could you be more precise?

Comment: I know what you mean HendrikD. Applying the curve modifier to the wave shape to make it confiorm to a circle. It's fine to do it this way - and gives the same result as the simple deform bend modifier. And indeed - I would prefer to use a curve for the wave shape in order to easily adjust the fit around the circumfrence, and have a lot more control of the smoothness. I've searched high and low for a curve shape solution, but aparrently Blender is quite limited with its curve/2D functionality.

Comment: I think I'm gonna have to go over some of the basics - I'm not used to creating profiles (in you step 1). I'm importing form an SVG, and it quiclkly becomes a mess when I try to subdevide in edit mode. Feeling quite disappointed that Blender can't handle this dynamically :(